# Why does unsynchronization make ArrayList faster and less secure?

Tags: java, concurrency, arraylist

I read the following statement:

> ArrayLists are unsynchronized and therefore faster than Vector, but less secure in a multithreaded environment.

I would like to know why unsynchronization can improve the speed, and why it will be less secure?

Comment: @Lukas, these are asking semantically different things.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, you're right because of "security"

Comment: @Lukas, yup.  That's what I was referring to.

Comment: synchronized has nothing to do with **security** and everything to do with thread **safety**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will try to address both of your questions:

> Improve speed

If the `ArrayList` were synchronized and multiple threads were trying to read data out of the list at the same time, the threads would have to wait to get an exclusive lock on the list.  By leaving the list unsynchronized, the threads don't have to wait and the program will run faster.

> Unsafe

If multiple threads are reading *and* writing to a list at the same time, the threads can have unstable view of the list, and this can cause instability in multi-threaded programs.

Comment: @jinguy `ArrayList`s are not considered faster than `Vector`s in multi-threaded contexts; it is the single-threaded context in which the extra synchronization overhead in `Vector`s that make them slower than `ArrayList`s.

Comment: @Binil: jjnguy's reasoning seems correct to me.  Plus, I would assume that synchronization operations are left out by the JVM if it only has one thread running.  So why would a `Vector` be considered the same speed as an `ArrayList` for multi-threaded programs?

Comment: @jinguy - there is no such thing as a "single threaded" java program.  pretty much any normal jvm is running multiple other threads besides the "main" thread.  @Binil is correct, people generally refer to it being faster for "single threaded" usage.  that said, jinguy is _also_ correct that it is faster for read-only multi-threaded usage as well.

Comment: @Karmastan @jjnguy the JVM tries hard to figure out if an object is used only by a single thread and avoid the cost of synchronization - biased locking, escape analysis etc - but it is far from perfect.

Comment: @jtahlborn Agreed; when an `ArrayList` is created, populated and safely published, subsequent reads do not need any extra synchronization, even when used by multiple threads. For `Vector`s a similar usage pattern will pay the extra cost of synchronization during reads.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of synchronization is that it means only one thread has access to an object at any given time. Take a box of chocolates as an example. If the box is synchronized (Vector), and you get there first, no one else can take any and you get your pick. If the box is NOT synchronized (ArrayList), anyone walking by can snag a chocolate - It will disappear faster, but you may not get the ones you want.

Answer (score 2):

> ArrayLists are unsynchronized and
>   therefore faster than Vector, but less
>   secure in a multithreaded environment.
>
> I would like to know why
>   unsynchronization can improve the
>   speed,and why it will be less secure?

When multiple threads are reading/writing to a shared memory location, the program might compute incorrect results due to lack of mutual exclusion and proper visibility. Hence lack of synchronization is considered "unsafe". [This blog post](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/08/atomicity-visibility-and-ordering.html) by Jeremy Manson might provide a good introduction to the topic.

When the JVM executes a synchronized method, it makes sure that the current thread has an exclusive lock on the object on which the method is invoked. Similarly when the method finishes execution, the JVM releases the lock held by the executing thread. Synchronized methods provide mutual exclusion and visibility guarantees - and is important for "safety" (i.e. guaranteeing correctness) of the executing code. But, if only one thread is ever accessing the methods of the object, there is no safety  issues to worry about. Although the JVM performance has improved over the years, uncontended synchronization (i.e. locking/unlocking of objects accessed by only one thread) still takes non-zero amount of time. For unsynchronized methods, the JVM does not pay this extra penalty - hence they are faster than their synchronized counterparts.

`Vector`s force their choice on you. All methods are `synchronized` and it is difficult to use them incorrectly. But when `Vector`s are used in a single-threaded context, you pay the price for the extra synchronization unnecessarily. `ArrayList`s leave the choice to you. When used in the multi-threaded context, it is up to you (the programmer) to correctly synchronizing the code; but when used in a single-threaded context you are guaranteed not to pay any extra synchronization overhead.

Also, when an collection is populated initially, and read subsequently `ArrayList`s perform better even in a multi-threaded context. For example, consider this method:

```
public synchronized List<String> getList() {
    List<String> list = new Vector<String>();
    list.add("Foo");
    list.add("Bar");
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

A list is created, populated, and an immutable view of it is safely published. Looking at the code above it is clear that all subsequent uses of this list are reads and won't need any synchronization even when used by multiple threads - the object is *effectively immutable*. Using a `Vector` here incurs the synchronization overhead even for reads where it is not needed; using an `ArrayList` instead would perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Non-blocking data structures will be faster than ones that bock, because of that fact. With blocking data structures, if a resources is acquired by some entity it will take time for another entity to acquire that same resource, once it becomes available.

However, this can be less secure in some instances depending on the situation. The main points of contention are during writes. If it can be guaranteed that the data contained in a data structure will not change it has been added and will only be accessed to read the value than there will not be a problem. The issues arise when there is a conflict between a write and a read, or a write and a write.

Comment: @jinguy Because they are constructed with compare-and-swap operations to ensure that all participating threads see a consistent view of the data, but without using large synchronized blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Data structures that synchronize use locks (or other synchronization constructs) to ensure that their data is always in a consistent state. Oftentimes, this requires that one or more threads wait on another thread to finish updating the structure's state, which will then reduce performance, since a wait has been introduced where before there was none.

Answer (score 0):

2 threads can modify the list at the same time and add a new item or delete/modify the same item in the list at the same time because no synchronization (or lock mechanism if you prefer) exists. So imagine you delete one item of the list while somebody else is trying to work with it or you modify an item while someone uses it, it's not very secure.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
Read the "Note that this implementation is not synchronized." paragraph, it explains a bit better.

And I forgot, considering speed, it seems quite trivial to imagine that when you try to control the access to a data, you add some mechanisms that prevent other people from accessing your data. Thus, you add some more computations so it is slower...